# WildFly 21.0.0.Final: Where can I find "filter-ref" in the GUI management console?

Tags: wildfly, undertow

I've configured in `standalone.xml`:

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:11.0" default-server="default-server" default-virtual-host="default-host" default-servlet-container="default" default-security-domain="other" statistics-enabled="true">
  <!-- ... -->
  <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
    <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
    <!-- Where to find in the GUI management console? -->
    <filter-ref name="test" predicate="equals(%p, 8282)"/>
    <!-- ... -->
```

but in the GUI management console I cannot find the `filter-ref` and the `predicate` attribute under

```
index.html#configuration;path=configuration~subsystems!css~undertow
```

Where to search?

```
WildFly 21.0.0.Final
Undertow 2.2.2.Final
```

Answer (score 0):

I am working with version 11 and I could edit an existing filter using the GUI under:
Configuration > Subsystems > Web > Filters > Expression Filter